# Issue with drupal 6 theme('username',...)

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-theming

I'm trying to print the full name of user instead of the username using `theme('username',$name);`  The full name is displayed but with as a hyperlink (in between `<a>..</a>`) which links to the user's profile page.  I just want `theme()` to output the full name as plain text. Can anyone help?

Comment: What is the $name variable? Is it the full name that you are trying to output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please could you say from where you are trying to print the username.

If you are doing this in the template.php, you can get it say from node_preprocess or page_preprocess using:

```
print $vars['user']->name;
```

Or if you are in a .tpl file you can use

```
<?php print $user->name; ?>
```

User is a global variable so you can grab all kinds of information from it.
If you want to see the available information try putting this in the template.php, say in page_preprocess function / (hook)

```
print_r ($vars['user']);
```